# dynamically add number of rows to table

Tags: jquery, html

i am working on a form where i have to get value from jquery spinner and add that number of rows to the table inside form but i dont know where is the issue exactly as i fire bug it as well but it do not show me any error.

below is my html

```
<div class="order-listing">
    <table id="my-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>
                <input type="text" name="name" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="name" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="name" />
                <select>
                    <option value"">abc</option>
                    <option value"">abc</option>
                    <option value"">abc</option>
                    <option value"">abc</option>
                </select>     
            </td></tr>              
        </tbody>
    </table>                  
</div>
```

and below is the jquery code for addition of rows

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({ min: 0 });
    $( "#ok" ).click(function() {
        var spiner_val = spinner.spinner( "value" ) ;
        var html = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="name" />'+
                    '<input type="text" name="name" /><input type="text" name="name" />'+
                    '<select><option value"">abc</option><option value"">abc</option>'+
                    '<option value"">abc</option><option value"">abc</option></select></td></tr>';

        $('#my-table > tbody > tr').eq(spiner_val).after(html);
    });
    $( "button" ).button();
});
</script>
```

below is the spinner and the ok button which trigger this functionality

```
<p>
    <label for="spinner">New Lines Required:</label>
    <input id="spinner" name="value" />
    <input type="button" value="OK" id="ok" />
</p>
```

Comment: why down votingggggg??????

Comment: Someday , at some universe -- the  Stackoverflow programmers- will be smart enough to not allow downvote without any comment.

Comment: @kwk.stack: Some people are sitting here just to do these kind of stuff only. They have must reputation (points) so they start spending now. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, use a for loop and add the html

```
 for(i = 0; i < spiner_val;i++){
     $(html).insertAfter('tr:last');
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLZhw/)

Comment: yes it worked thanks alot but down voting by programmers for this question realy disheart me

Comment: @kwk.stack You're welcome btw option value"" should be value="". Got no idea why your question got downvoted :/

Comment: ohhh thank you so much for correction as well :)  i know i can get upvoting on a question like "what are the spellings of fox??" becuse the question i asked above was not acceptable